# How to force git use SSH authentication?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a problem with GIT.

1. Remote URL is git@gitlab.com:jvavruska/log73r.git
2. I have my key pair set up and public key registered at gitlab.com
3. `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` returns:

```
    Welcome to GitLab, @jvavruska!
```

4. but when I try `git push`, `git push origin master`, etc. it always returns

```
   FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
```

I could not anything in the Git documentation to explain how to force git use SSH for authentication. No CL option, just nothing...

My `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`:

```
Host gitlab.com
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile C:\Users\jvavruska\.ssh\id_ed25519
```

Comment: Have you added your public key to gitlab? Profile -> Settings -> SSH Keys. With Bash ` cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip`  and paste it into the textarea.

Comment: Some things to debug: 1. Can you verify with `git remote -v` that the URL is indeed `git@gitlab.com:jvavruska/log73r.git` and not `https://...`? 2. Did you try this in CMD and GitBash? 3. Try specifying the command via gitconfig (you can even try to use some `verbose` flags to get more information), see: https://github.com/darekkay/config-files/blob/master/git/.gitconfig#L23

Comment: I suspect that your Git *is* using ssh, and suspect it's probably just running a *different* ssh than the one you've configured correctly. Try running with `GIT_TRACE=1`, e.g., `GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master`, to observe each underlying command as it progresses.

Comment: Answers: John Pavek: yes, I did (mentioned in the question), Darek Kay: yes, it is (actually I set it up just before I needed to push); torek: you almost hit the spot (see my answer below). Thank you for help and I apologize for creating stupid mistakes myself.

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry and I apologize.
Stupid mistake: GIT_SSH variable was set to .... plink.exe. Most likely my older, previous setup (which *should* work with the existing .ppk file, but for some reason didn't).
I changed `GIT_SSH=ssh` (yes, without path!) and immediately everything started moving in the right direction.
Once more, sorry.